# How to update a large table of 25 GB, more than 350 million records of MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

How to update a large table of 25 GB, more than 350 million records of MyISAM?
I need to set a random date in the `time` field for all records. On a server without load, the command was executed:

```
UPDATE table SET time = FROM_UNIXTIME(1451595600 + FLOOR((RAND() * 31536000)))
```

mysqld loaded the processor and took up a lot of RAM, in the morning the load on the server is minimal, but the query is all executed, more than 55 hours have passed.

[image]

I can not understand what's going on!

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `job_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `lock` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `job_id` (`job_id`),
    KEY `lock` (`lock`),
    KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

ADD:

```
root@lw4:~ # iostat -p md1 60 5
```

[image]

SOLVED:

I interrupted the update process.

Removed indexes except the primary:

```
MariaDB [base]> ALTER TABLE `table` DROP INDEX `job_id`, DROP INDEX `lock`, DROP INDEX `time`;
Query OK, 339468609 rows affected (1 hour 3 min 28.89 sec)
Records: 339468609  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Update `time` field:

```
MariaDB [base]> UPDATE `table` SET `time` = FROM_UNIXTIME(1451595600 + FLOOR((RAND() * 31539599)));
Query OK, 339468609 rows affected (16 min 8.09 sec)
Rows matched: 339468609  Changed: 339468609  Warnings: 0
```

Add indexes:

```
MariaDB [base]> ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX (`job_id`), ADD INDEX (`lock`), ADD INDEX (`time`);
Query OK, 339468609 rows affected (2 hours 18 min 58.32 sec)
Records: 339468609  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Total update time: 3 hours 38 min 35.3 sec

Comment: Sorry, but your question is hard to understand. Please be more precise: _has_ the query terminated correctly or not? Has the column been updated or not?

Comment: It might be of interest what indexes exist on that table. Please add the information about creation of table and indexes to the question.

Comment: The table is still being updated, but I'm concerned that it's been a long time. And most of this time the server is not loaded

Comment: It might be that the bottleneck is disk operation due to the fact that MyISAM tables are stored directly on disk which is a pretty write intense approach. That is why I asked about the indexes. It might be that the server tries to rewrote the whole table or each index after updating each row.

Comment: The MyISAM files located on Sata RAID 10

Comment: What difference does that make?

Comment: In the case if MyISAM, if you abort the `UPDATE`, some of the rows will be updated; the rest won't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **Drop all the indexes** of that table. Also, **drop the foreign key constraint** if any. Then **fire update query**. After the update is complete then **create all indexes and constraint again**.

Creating of all indexes and constraint will take time but it will much less as compared to updating the table directly.

Comment: Who down votes this answer and why? This might not necessarily be an answer to the question, but the hints certainly do make sense!

Comment: (1) MyISAM does not support FKs; (2) dropping all indexes is overkill.

Comment: I interrupted the update process. Removed indexes except the primary, update \`time\` field, add indexes. Total update time: 3 hours 38 min 35.3 sec

Comment: I tried insert 2 GB data from the dump and it was took very long time and I lost my patient later I removed all indexes and tried again, it is done within 2 minutes. Thank you Himanshu dua

Answer (score 0):

Here's what is going on...

Each record was initially 13 bytes.  After updating a row, it will be 17 bytes (old version of MySQL) or 18 bytes (newer version).

This means that the updated row cannot simply replace the old row, but must be put somewhere else and then free up the old space.  The first such update will go to the end of the table.  Or maybe it uses the 13-6 bytes from the old space, then puts a link to where it put the rest of the new row.

The second row then does something similarly messy.

So, the operation is bounding around in the table, and making the data quite fragmented.

Also, the index for `time` is being rebuilt (using the key_buffer).  Since it is "random", the updates to the index BTree are random.  If the key_buffer is not big enough, then there will be a lot of I/O for that.  This particular aspect can be sped up by `DROPping` that index beforehand and re-ADDing it afterwards.  Alas, both the `DROP` and `ADD` will be slow, but not nearly as slow as the incremental building of the index.

You really ought to move to InnoDB, which does both the data update and the index update quite differently and alters -- and more efficiently.  One caution:  The table+indexes will take 2-3 times as much disk space as MyISAM.

Do you really need all 4 indexes?

For MyISAM, the value of `key_buffer_size` is important.  For InnoDB, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.